# Scipy.io not loading data

Tags: python, scipy, mat

I'm trying to use scipy.io to load the contents of a .mat file to a python dictionary. This seems to be working except in regard for the data in the table "data". This seems to be working regardless of the file I'm loading. Is there a way to fix this, or a workaround that I can use? I've looked into mat4py, mat73, mat2py and I can't seem to get any of them working. The code definitely finds the correct file.

```
import scipy as sp
import os
Dir=r"Directory"
os.chdir(Dir)
mat_contents = scipy.io.loadmat("file")
mat_contents['data']
```

This returns the following error `"KeyError: 'data'"`
In addition,
`mat_contents.keys()`
Gives the following error
dict_keys(['**header**', '**version**', '**globals**', 'None', '**function_workspace**'])

Comment: It does not look like this file has a `data` variable.  I don't recognize this `function_workspace`.  Have you tried examining it?

Comment: If I look into it, it's just an array with some seemingly random numbers, nothing related to my data.